# IOS and Android : insecure resource 'gap://ready'. This content should also be served over HTTPS

Tags: android, ios, cordova, https

I want to loading external URL (https) inside my webview cordova.

**My content security**

```
⟨meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: cdvfile://* gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com https://*  http://*   'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src https://*  'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; media-src *"⟩
```

**Android error :** Mixed Content: The page at 'https://mydomaine.net' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure resource 'gap://ready'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

**IOS error :** Message from debugger: Terminated due to memory issue

my config.xml

```
<content src="https://mydomaine.net" />
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" spec="1" />
<access origin="*" subdomains="true"  launch-external="true"/>
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" subdomains="true" />
<allow-intent href="tel:*" />
<allow-intent href="sms:*" />
<allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
<allow-intent href="geo:*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" subdomains="true" />
<allow-navigation href="data:*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" /> 
<allow-navigation href="*://*/*"/>
<access origin="http://*/*" launch-external="true" />
<access origin="https://*/*" subdomains="true" launch-external="true"/>
<access origin="content:///*" launch-external="true" />
<access origin="cdvfile://*"  launch-external="true" />
```

I don't use plugin inappbrower because I can't access to my device with inappbrower

Any ideas?

Comment: did you ever find a solution?